# How to pass clicked file full path to a batch command shortcut that is set as a defualt program to open some specific file types

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have a batch command (set as the default program to open all image files) that runs the following command

rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen %1

this is suppose to open windows picture viewer perhaps

Now in the %1 i have to pass the desired picture which is surely accessed from windows UI.  But how will i tell it which file is it suppose to open ? How do i pass the double clicked file's full path in the parameter of the batch command, is not there any environment variable that holds the last accessed file's full path ?

Answer (score 3):

No. Batch files have this problem, but it is avoided because the passed parameter includes the full path to the particular file. You must, however, enclose the parameter in quotes to avoid any error if the full path name would (will!) include spaces:

```
rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen "%1"
```

On the other hand, you may also drag-and-drop several file names to your Batch file. In this case, you must process they in the usual way via a loop with a SHIFT command:

```
:nextfile
if "%1" == "" goto endfiles
  rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen "%1"
  shift
  goto nextfile
:endfiles
```

Comment: +1, But `if "%1" == "" goto endfiles` should be `if "%~1" == "" goto endfiles`, else you got problems with spaces in the path, and this fails always with filenames like `me&you.bmp`